# Is this set open or closed or neither of both in $\Bbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I'm solving this problem in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis:*

[image]

and came up with a idea that is $\{p \in \Bbb{Q} \mid 2 < p^2 < 3 \}$ open or closed in $\Bbb{R}$ or neither of both? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. The limit point $\sqrt{2}$ is not in the set, so not closed. The set contains no interval, so not open.

Comment: The set is not closed in $\Bbb{R}$, but it is in $\Bbb{Q}$, since $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are not in $\Bbb{Q}$;

Comment: Ok, u r right. I think i've made a mistake on my understanding of definition of limit point. I made a conclusion that property of closed or open is decided by the space where the set in and all elements the set contained; compact is decided by the measure involved and all elements the set contained and not by the space where it is in, is that right?

Comment: @Frank_W:Yes. Specifically, if $A$ is a topological subspace of both $X$ and $Y$, then $A$ is compact in $X$ if and only if it is compact in $Y$. Note that the requirement of subspace is necessary, because if $X$ and $Y$ have completely different topology, it's quite possible that $A$ is compact in one and not another.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** You can regard $\Bbb{Q}$ as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}$. Check that
$$E=\Bbb{Q}\cap \left( (-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2})\cup (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})\right)=\Bbb{Q}\cap \left( [-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2}]\cup [\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]\right)
$$
So $E$ is both open and closed in $\Bbb{Q}$. However, $E$ does not contain any open subinterval so $E$ is not open in $\Bbb{R}$, and $\overline{E}\neq E$ (in $\Bbb{R}$) so ...

Comment: Ok, u r right. I think i've made a mistake on my understanding of definition of limit point. I made a conclusion that property of closed or open is decided by the space where the set in and all elements the set contained; compact is decided by the measure involved and all elements the set contained and not by the space where it is in, is that right?

Comment: @Frank_W The concept of the openness, closedness and compactness are depend on the entire space (exactly, it depends on the topology.)